# Check for duplicate entries in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

`Dog` and `Cat` class inherited from the `Animal` class and if I want to add in `ArrayList`, I use the codes

```
pets.add(new Dog(name))
```

How can I find out if a name is used more than once?

I'm looking for something like : `pets.contain(...)`

Comment: Do you want to find out a names that are used more than once, or do you want to check if a name is in use before you add?  You question and your last line means different thing

Comment: Why can't you use set, instead of using ArrayList in this case

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a [contains method on List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)).  It uses the equals method to check for equality, so if your `Dog` or `Cat` classes implement `equals` in a way that the same name means equality, you can simply use `contains`.

If for some reason you don't want to do that (because you need equality to mean something else), you can just iterate over the list and find an entry with the same name.  Or alternatively, use a stream, like so: `pets.stream().filter(pet -> pet.getName().equals(newName)).findAny().isPresent()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java8 you can use something like:

```
pets.stream().map(animal -> animal.getName()).contains(name);
```

which will return boolean whether name is already in List.

Another way is using for loop:

```
boolean isNamePresent = false;
for (Animal pet: pets) {
    if(pet.getname().equals(name)) {
        isNamePresent = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way of doing this with a native function.

You could try the following:

```
int number = 0;
for (int i=0; i<pets.size(); i++){ 
    if pets.get(i).getname().equalsIgnoreCase("nameYouWant") number++;
}
```

Comment: Can I do without for looping?

Comment: without looping, the only way of doing this is with an stream: 
                                    pets.stream().filter(elem -> elem.getName().equals("NameYouWant")).count();

Comment: Why so eager to avoid a loop?  A stream ill be worse, performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous.

If you want to find from a list, names that are used more than once, you can do something like

```
pets.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Animall::getName(), Collectors.counting()))
     .entrySet().stream()
     .filter(e->e.getValue() > 1)
     .map(e->e.getKey())
     .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

which will give you a `List<String>` containing names appeared more than once

---

If you just want to check if a name exists in `pets` before you add to it, I think you should use `Map<String, Animal>` instead of a `List`.